# How to pass parameter to @Query annotation with hql

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hql

Here is my hql requete :

```
@Query("select a from Agent where a.visibility = true a order by a.id desc")
public Page<Agent> getAllAgents(Pageable pageable);
```

I want to select all agents that have visibility true.

In my Agent class a have Boolean visibility attribute with getVisibility and setVisibility functions. In my data base "visibility" stored as bit(1).

I tried a.visibility = 1, ... = '1', ...= 'TRUE', ...='true', ... is true. But i get this error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: a near line 1, column 74 [select a from com.GemCrmTickets.entities.Agent where a.visibility = true a order by a.id desc]
```

Any suggestions ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you use `@Query("select a from Agent where a.visibility = 1 a order by a.id desc")` you can't get the same error

Comment: You have an `a` after `true` in your query which makes the query invalid.

Comment: Don't ask the same question over and over!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct, you have an extra `a` between `true` and `order by...`. So the correct query would become like this

```
select a from Agent a where a.visibility = true order by a.id desc
```

Not sure if that fixes all your troubles. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
@Query("select a from Agent a where a.visibility = true order by a.id desc")
public Page<Agent> getAllAgents(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have to write the Alice name of the table so add it.

```
@Query("select a from Agent a where a.visibility = true order by a.id desc")
```